# SQL like & matches query on string in Swift

Tags: swift, match, sql-like, string-comparison

I want to write a function that can perform comparison with two strings.

Something like this:

```
func stringComparison(_ str1:String, comparisonOperator:StringComparisonOperator, _ str2:String)
{
   ...
}
```

I want to support the following types in the `StringComparisonOperator`

```
enum StringComparisonOperator {
    case equals
    case contains
    case beginsWith
    case endsWith
    case like
    case matches
}
```

Swift provides `==`(for equals), `.contains`(for contains), `.hasPrefix`(for beginsWith) and `.hasSuffix`(for endsWith).

But, I don't have any idea about `like` and `matches` options. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: What is the format of str2, does it contain sql wildcards or is it a regular expression or...?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Its a regex

Comment: Then the answer below should work for both like and matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an infix operator for **like** and **matches**

```
infix operator =~
func =~ (string: String, regex: String) -> Bool {
    return string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```

and use like: `"abcd" =~ "ab*cd"`